# Elements inside `overflow-x: hidden` still have width (Safari)

Tags: jquery, css, safari, overflow

The following code demonstrates an element, `p`, that collapses and expands horizontally with CSS3 (actually webkit) transitions:

```
<style>
  div * {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  p {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s;
  }​
</style>

<div>
  <a><i>begin</i><p><s>middle</s></p><b>end</b></a>
  <a id="after">after</a>
</div>

<script>
  $('div > a').each(function() {
    var a, p;
    a = $(this);
    p = $('p', a);
    a.toggle((function() {
      p.width(0);
    }), function() {
      p.width(p[0].scrollWidth);
    });
  });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qrf3E/

It has the desired effect when using Chrome:
http://www.screenr.com/vJH7

But in Safari (desktop and mobile) the apparent width of the container element, `a`, snaps back to the expanded width when the inner container, `p`, has collapsed. This forces the following element, `#after`, to float out in space... 
Help! Is this a Safari bug? Can anyone offer a fix?

http://www.screenr.com/qJH7

Answer (score 1):

One possible fix that has just occurred to me would be to collapse to a single pixel and then hide:

```js
a.toggle(function() {
  p.one('webkitTransitionEnd', function() {
    p.hide();
  });
  p.width(1);
}, function() {
  p.show();
  p.width(p[0].scrollWidth);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/corin/LsSk2/

Can anyone better that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems to be a forgotten default value by the safari developers.

If you set `a { display: inline; }` it works. http://jsfiddle.net/2t388/

Comment: Thank you! I shall try it in the real world project where I hit this problem and see if it works